# Does Sklean have a Gaussian Discriminant Analysis (GDA)

Tags: normal-distribution, scikit-learn, discriminant-analysis

I was trying to look for the Gaussian Discriminant Analysis in sklearn however I was unsuccessful and I was wondering what it the name of it. I was about to find the LinearDiscriminantAnalysis and  QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis but not the Gaussian Discriminant Analysis

Comment: If [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/19054/269787) is correct, then GDA is a general term to refer to both LDA and QDA.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not totally sure, I think sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB is what you want to look at: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB

I tried it with some simple data with only one feature, and the result from GaussianNB is identical to my understanding of GDA (which I learned from stanford CS229).

Update on 07/28/2021: I tried a simple dataset with two features today and realized that GDA is not entirely the same as GaussianNB (although they ARE the same if there is only one feature): GaussianNB (from sklearn) simply calculate the variance for each feature individually without worrying about the correlation between two features (In other words, in the Gaussian fit for P(x|y), $\Sigma$ (the covariance matrix) is diagonal). However, GDA does not assume a diagonal $\Sigma$ (The $\Sigma$ is calculated using maximum likelihood estimation), so I think GDA's performance will be better.